# Removing CSS texts on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am styling using javascript. How to hide css styles text on my html? It seems if I put css styles using javascript,it will show on my html.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpWky.png)

Comment: Short answer is: Don't use JavaScript to add CSS styles then! Perhaps you could move all these styles in to a single CSS class then add the class using JS or even add the class to your HTML source.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the HTML as text rather than in a screeshot.

Comment: What do you mean by "hide" them?

Comment: sorry but this was the objective of my bootcamp activity. to use only javascript on html and css. So i was just wondering if theres a way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding separate style in javascript. You can add classes which will have all the styling:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("myDiv");
element.classList.add("myStyle");
```

```css
.myStyle {
display: flex;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color: green;
justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: @axie chi  Please tick if you got the answer.